# Get today's date in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get today's date, is this the correct way to do it?

```
echo strftime("%e %h %Y", time());
```

Please note, I'm using strftime becuase I'm also using setlocale. To my knowledge I dont think you can use it with date.

Thanks

Comment: `echo date('d m Y');`

Comment: This doesnt work with setlocale

Comment: Not if your web server is Windows as %e is then not implemented. Try %x, as the month/day order may then be adjusted by locale. e.g. mm/dd/yy or dd/mm/yy. Deciding month/day ordering by locale or otherwise may cause confusion though, and it could be best to give the user the choice to set this as a user preference. What would an American living in London want to see, dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy for example? Maybe mm/dd/yy even though their region was Europe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL,"hu_HU.UTF8");
echo(strftime("%A %d %B  %Y"));
echo(strftime("%a %d %b  %y"));
echo(strftime("%w %d %m  %y"));  ?>
```

Top one echos:

`Thursday 18 July 2013`

Second one echos:

`Thu 18 Jul 13`

Third one echos:

`4 18 07 13`

(4) being thursday, fourth day into the week.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the date function :

```
echo date('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//will out put like 13-07-18 13:32:29
?>
```

Here is the Detail for additional Parameters :

[DATE IN PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP is running. It returns exactly what the system setlocale function returns.

Look : [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

This Mannual Includes written that

> Note:
>   The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP is running. It returns exactly what the system setlocale function returns.

Comment: The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP is running. It returns exactly what the system setlocale function returns.

Comment: its much related to your question,strftime — Format a local time/date according to locale settings.so whatever date/time you sets in your system,you will get that time.if there is a date 17July 2011 than its return same instead of 17july2013.

Comment: @beans: Don't mess with your locale's unless you _have_ to, just use the fromat `d-m-Y` and others, or use [the predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types). To Harshal Mahajan: +1 for the link

Answer (score 1):

That is correct however, you don't have to specify time(). The current timestamp will be used as a default value for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function:-

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  // set default time zone
echo date('format');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"hu_HU.UTF8");
echo(strftime("%Y. %B %d. %A. %X %Z"));
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit?